# Can I put C# and Java code in the same file to make porting my code easier?

Tags: java, c#, c-preprocessor

I am porting some code from C# to Java.  I'm finding that it's easy to miss code or make other mistakes.  I'm thinking that if I can have both versions of the code exist in the same file, then I could cut down on these mistakes.  I would edit only one file, just two parts of the file.

If Java had a pre-processor like C#'s (I know some projects are available that allow this), I could write something like this:

```
#if C_SHARP
namespace MyMath
{
    class NaiveFib
    {
        public int Run(int n)
        {
            if (n == 0) return 1;
            if (n == 1) return 1;
            return Run(n - 1) + Run(n - 2);
        }
    }
}
#elif JAVA
package MyMath;

public class NaiveFib
{
    public int Run(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) return 1;
        if (n == 1) return 1;
        return Run(n - 1) + Run(n - 2);
    }
}
#endif
```

I would still have a problem with my IDE recognizing that a file contains compilable code given that Java files are named *.java and C# files are named *.cs.  It looks like I can have Visual Studio think that *.java files are C# files if I check the right settings.  I wouldn't have to make any changes to my Java IDE (Eclipse).

Is this all possible?  And is it a good idea or is it more trouble than it's worth?

Comment: Even if this was possible, this would be an absolute **catastrophe** to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the idea is good, but the code would be hard to read. A mess. 
Maybe if you have a very simple codebase... but in reality would result **BIG CHAOS**!

You maybe spend a lot of time by looking at wrong code, scrolling up n down and getting more confused. Clean code in the files will have your focus, when you open your java project you know you work with java. And when you do open the c# you know it is C# etc.

Do a java branch and a c# branch of your code. It is more easy to maintain and keep it clean.

Think of situation where you want to upgrade the environment, why wasting time/money to recompile the Java code while you are about to upgrade only the C# code, etc!

Will you port to php, ruby, perl, python etc in same files too ?

Just let programmers to open the code they want to see and work with, separate files!

Some Java programmers might jump out of the window when they see C# code! Thought about it? ;)

Comment: **THIS**. There's absolutely no good reason to mash the two together. While C# and java share a lot of similarities, the relationship isn't quite this 1:1. Save yourself and future coders a headache, separate them out.

Comment: Totally agreed and +1. Also notice that if you have the same code in C# and Java, you are basically replicating your whole codebase... I would stick to one language/framework, if at all possible in OP's case.

Comment: @Renan In fact I will be replicating my whole code base so that it supports C# and Java.  I'm not looking forward to it.

Comment: @user2023861 Just **why** do you want or need to support two languages?

Comment: I'm writing some code that simulates an API.  The API returns data that is expensive.  My project acts just like the API, but returns fake data.  The people who would use this are interested in writing code that accesses the data, not the data itself.  It's a niche project, but it's getting plenty of downloads on Codeplex IMO (I won't plug it here).  Anyways, that API exists in several languages including C# and Java.  That's why I want to replicate my code in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is more trouble that it's woth because:

1. Every time you will have to scroll between two files
2. In almost every IDE you can hace code side by side
3. Viusal studio support J# syntax (which is almost Java), so you will have proper highlight in both files

Comment: is J# still supported? I thought i read that M$ discontinued support for it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a bootstrapping step to your build to extract the Java or C# code you want before you compile. Or just comment out the C# code if really all you want is this to work in Java.

Comment: I'm not downvoting this answer, because even though you are pushing te OP into a path of sure grief and gnashing of teeth (and probably laughing sadistically while doing that - I know I would do so), you are technically right.

Comment: You know what... +1 for that.

Comment: Actually what I asked for is if my solution will work, and if it is worth the trouble.  I don't know the best way to maintain code that has been ported to another language, but this is not it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you trying to port the program to? The Mono project has done a good job of increasing the platform accessibility of .net. Have you looked into that?

Answer (score 0):

Though you save no of files, but the disadvantage of this approach is you lose the basic concept of modularizing your project into different languages. 
Secondly, most of the other people reading your code wont find it that simple as you find to switch between different languages between the same file.
And lastly, you'll be wasting your time and resources in recompiling the complete code again and again (even the java code), though you made amendments to C# code only, for say.